# How to use an XOR like function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I cannot seem to get a grasp on the sql required to meet my needs for this question.
SO far I have:

```
select * from customformresponses
INNER JOIN exhibitors ON
Exhibitors.ExhibitorId= customformresponses.ExhibitorId
WHERE customformresponses.exhibitorid='8179cde9-b922-430a-9024-bd4cb8b3d05c'
  and exhibitors.exhibitionID = 'e641a3d4-cb57-4f67-86a1-5c2f4c3cf6e0'
  and customformresponses.FormID = 'c7f5f0de-35f8-412d-9c91-eaf8bb1a3c26'
```

I need to search for responses in 3 different formID values but the problem im having is if I have:

```
customformresponses.FormID = 'c7f5f0de-35f8-412d-9c91-eaf8bb1a3c26'  or
customformresponses.FormID = 'c7f5f0de-35f8-412d-9c91-eaf8bb1a3c26' or
customformresponses.FormID = 'e69cee39-2519-434d-be3e-516ba156b444'
```

Then it only returns the results of the first true condition not any of the true conditions.

How do you return all the results from the rows that meet this criteria?

Comment: What do you mean by XOR, do you mean the exhibitorid/exhibitionid must ONLY match one of the OR conditions?  Note: Your first 2 parts of the OR are identical.

Comment: You probably need parenthesis. `xx AND xx AND xx OR xx OR xx` is parsed as `(xx AND xx AND xx) OR xx OR xx`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after

```
select *
from customformresponses
INNER JOIN exhibitors
    ON Exhibitors.ExhibitorId= customformresponses.ExhibitorId
WHERE customformresponses.exhibitorid='8179cde9-b922-430a-9024-bd4cb8b3d05c'
AND exhibitors.exhibitionID = 'e641a3d4-cb57-4f67-86a1-5c2f4c3cf6e0'
AND
( customformresponses.FormID = 'c7f5f0de-35f8-412d-9c91-eaf8bb1a3c26'
  OR
  customformresponses.FormID = 'e69cee39-2519-434d-be3e-516ba156b444')
```

It will require matching exhibitorid and exhibitionid, but for the FormID, it will match any of the two.

So if you have two rows

```
exhibitorid      | exhibitionid     | formid
8179cde9-b922... | c7f5f0de-35f8... | c7f5f0de-35f8-412d-9c91-eaf8bb1a3c26
8179cde9-b922... | c7f5f0de-35f8... | e69cee39-2519-434d-be3e-516ba156b444
```

Both of them will be in the output resultset

Answer (score 0):

If only to avoid repeating the GUIDs and column names...

```
SELECT *
FROM customformresponses
  INNER JOIN exhibitors ON Exhibitors.ExhibitorId = customformresponses.ExhibitorId
WHERE (
  CASE customformresponses.exhibitorid WHEN '8179cde9-b922-430a-9024-bd4cb8b3d05c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE exhibitors.exhibitionID WHEN 'e641a3d4-cb57-4f67-86a1-5c2f4c3cf6e0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE customformresponses.FormID WHEN 'c7f5f0de-35f8-412d-9c91-eaf8bb1a3c26' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from customformresponses 
INNER JOIN exhibitors     
ON Exhibitors.ExhibitorId= customformresponses.ExhibitorId 
WHERE customformresponses.exhibitorid='8179cde9-b922-430a-9024-bd4cb8b3d05c' 
AND exhibitors.exhibitionID = 'e641a3d4-cb57-4f67-86a1-5c2f4c3cf6e0' 
AND ormresponses.FormID IN  ( 'c7f5f0de-35f8-412d-9c91-eaf8bb1a3c26', 'e69cee39-2519-434d-be3e-516ba156b444')
```